# Ensure the sum of amounts is zero

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I have a database with basically 3 tables:

`accounts` <-- `operations` --> `orders`

I would like to allow transactions of money from *n* accounts to *m* accounts.

For instance, let's consider a transaction of $11 from Alice and Sophia to Bob ans Joe:

```
| Sender | Receiver |
| ------ | -------- | ------ |
|      1 |          | Alice  |
|     10 |          | Sophia |
|        |        6 | Bob    |
|        |        5 | Joe    |
```

What I would like to ensure is that, the sum of the moved amount is always equal to zero (in this example: `(1 + 10) - (6 + 5) == 0`).

In this example, I would have 4 rows inside the `operations` table.

Until now, I did some control using an programming language such as PHP to ensure that the sum is always zero. But I would really prefer to ensure it on the physical layer, with MySQL.

Also, if possible, I would prefer to DRY the amount which is equal between the sender and the receiver sides. Right now, I don't think that my database structure is normalized. Do you think m

Thank you for your feedback/advice!

**Edit**

There is what the SQL tables look like:

```
____________
| accounts |
| -------- |
| id       |
------------
______________
| operations |
| ---------- |
| id         |
| account_id |
| order_id   |
| amount     | <- can be positive or negative
--------------
__________
| orders |
| ------ |
| id     |
----------
```

Comment: Include your db schema, right now Im not sure how is that working for you. Please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You will probably need a [Stored Procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)

Comment: What if the amounts don't total zero?

Comment: @Strawberry Well, if it's not zero, there's a trouble in the financial transaction. This must never happen. That's why I would like to have a protection right from the MySQL layer.